# Spotfire - How to add a reload button

Tags: refresh, reload, spotfire, tibco

How to add a button and whenever user clicks on the button the data reloads.

Also the user should know when the data gets refreshed.

Comment: Have you followed the steps at this link? https://community.tibco.com/wiki/how-refresh-or-reload-data-using-ironpython-script-tibco-spotfire

Comment: @MarkP. I'd post that as an answer, as it is a perfect solution

Answer (score 3):

You could use this python script, as found [here](https://community.tibco.com/wiki/how-refresh-or-reload-data-using-ironpython-script-tibco-spotfire).

```
from System.Collections.Generic import List, Dictionary 
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataTable 
from System.Collections import ArrayList

#Refreshing a single Data table:
dataTable.Refresh() // where dataTable is a script parameter of type DataTable

#Refreshing multiple tables:
#Note that more than one table can be added to the List object.
tables = ArrayList()
tables.Add(Document.Data.Tables["DataTable1"]) 
tables.Add(Document.Data.Tables["DataTable2"]) 
Document.Data.Tables.Refresh(tables)
#As such DataTableCollection.Refresh Method refreshes the given tables in dependency order.
#OR
Document.Data.Tables.RefreshAsync(tables)
#And DataTableCollection.RefreshAsync Method (IEnumerable< DataTable> ) refreshes the given tables in dependency order. 
#Tables that have asynchronous refresh (i.e. Data On Demand and Data Functions) and tables that depend on them will be refreshed 
#in later transactions.

# Another possible option:

Tbls = List[DataTable]() 
Tbls.Add(Document.Data.Tables["DataTable1"]) 
Tbls.Add(Document.Data.Tables["DataTable2"]) 
for i in Tbls:
 Document.Data.Tables.Refresh([i])
```

In order to let the user know when the data was refreshed, just set a document property with the current date/time and surface that document property in a text area. When the script above is run, the date/time will update.

Also, have a look at their Python API page located [here](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/spotfire/7.6.0/doc/api/?topic=html/T_Spotfire_Dxp_Application_Visuals_LineChart.htm) (for 7.6, but the newer 7.12 API can be found as well). While it is organized in a slightly frustrating way, you can get a feel for methods and classes you can call in your script to do all sorts of things programmatically.